# CSS3 - style part of div after <br /> tag

Tags: css

I have following div:

```
<div class="mydiv">
     This is some introduction text
     <br />
     click me
</div>
```

Is it possible to style the `click me` differently than the rest of the div using CSS only?

Comment: Wrap it in a span. Style the span.

Comment: Or even better, an `a` or `button`, since I guess you want it to be clickable

Comment: I don't have access to that part of code. I know I can use JavaScript for this, was just curious if it's possible to do this CSS only way

Comment: Oh, ONLY CSS? No. CSS Selectors are tag, class, and id granular. I don't know of how they could be told "select the text anfter this tag that isn't wrapped in a tag or otherwise labeled."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can style the `:first-line` differently. If there's only 2 lines, it's **kind of** feasible to style the 2nd and last line than the first one in pure CSS.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/qRqPeq)

BUT

- you can't style [every property (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line)
- being certain that a text will occupy exactly 2 lines would be ignoring narrow devices like smartphones (hello RWD) or zooming at the will of each user (graphical or text zooming). The web is not a PDF :)

+1 to Pevara suggestion: it should be a link or a button and then it can easily be styled

```css
div {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: red;
}
div::first-line {
  text-transform: initial;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<p>OK</p>
<div class="mydiv">
     This is some introduction text
     <br />
     click me
</div>
<hr>
<p>#fail</p>
<div class="mydiv" style="width: 100px; border: 1px dotted blue">
     This is some introduction text
     <br />
     click me
</div>
```

Comment: great solution. for me wrapping would be really cumbersome as text comes from a user input field

Answer (score 1):

No, without modifying the HTML or using JavaScript there is no pure CSS way to select the text `click me`.